# Stop Jupyterlab scroll down in the code cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

It makes me really annoying that the code cell in the Jupyterlab often scrolls down so that I cannot scroll down to the cell that I want:
[image]

So is there a way to stop or shut-off this scrolling within code cell?

Thanks,

Comment: This looks like a bug. I never seen that before. Please report this with full information needed to reproduce at https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab

Comment: @krassowski See https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/8442 and https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/8746

Comment: Can you reproduce it in JupyterLab 4 alpha? You can try it without installation by clicking on the binder badge in https://gist.github.com/jtpio/4e9a3d435d7c3950dc4150c10abbb1d7 (JupyterLab 4 will ship with a new version of CodeMirror editor so all of this is going to be refactored).